# Hide a div section conditionally by java script

Tags: javascript, html

I want to hide a div section from javascript, i have code like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var error='<%= session.getAttribute("errormsg") %>';
        alert(error);
        if(error!=null){
            document.getElementById('loginform').style.display = "hidden";
            alert("ok");
        }

    });
```

here `alert(error);` is working fine means its printing if `error` is `null` or not, But irrespective of this it always print `alert("ok");`.
And `document.getElementById('loginform').style.display = "hidden";` never works.

what is wrong in this code.

Comment: Try **if(error)** to check if error is null or not

Comment: `document.getElementById('loginform').style.display = "none"` will work

Comment: Can you remove the `java` tag from this question?  Does not seem relevant to Java in any manner.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just use .hide().

```
**   $(document).ready(function() {
        var error='<%= session.getAttribute("errormsg") %>';
        alert(error);
        if(error!=null){
            $('#loginform').hide()
            alert("ok");
        }

    });**
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
document.getElementById('loginform').style.display = "none";
```

Comment: CSS `style` property supports `none` and not `hidden` and hence this should work.

Answer (score 1):

it good if you use undefined in javascript as below

```
if(typeof variable_here === 'undefined'){
   // your code here.
 };
```

so for you it will be like

```
if(typeof error!==null){
            //make use of none insted of hidden to hide element completly
            //if you use hidden it will consume space on you page 
            //with none it will not consume space
            document.getElementById('loginform').style.display = "none";
            alert("ok");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using java scriptlet in javascript code is not a good practice as javascript is runs on client side and java scriptlet on server side. I suggest you should use a hidden field say `errorMsg` and use its value in javascript. as follows,

```
<input type="hidden" id="errorMsg" value="${errormsg}">
```

And modify your code as,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var error=document.getElementById('errorMsg').value;
    alert(error);
    if(error!=null){
        document.getElementById('loginform').style.display = "none";
        alert("ok");
    }

});
```

Also use of `none` instead of 'hidden' is a good practice unless you want your hidden element to consume space.

Answer (score 0):

```
use  document.getElementById('loginform').style.display = "none";

it will work fine

Or u can also use document.getElementById('loginform').style.visibility = "hidden";
```